# why does the dictonary not update?

Tags: python

this is a function from my tic tac toe.
when i run this functions in a while loop multiple times, the values of the keys in dic always remain the same (1,2,3,...) I wanted them to change after "dic[field] = current_player" and stay in this condition

```
def user_input():
    dic = {
        "empty_1": "1",
        "empty_2": "2",
        "empty_3": "3",
        "empty_4": "4",
        "empty_5": "5",
        "empty_6": "6",
        "empty_7": "7",
        "empty_8": "8",
        "empty_9": "9",
    }
    print(dic["empty_2"]) # always prints out 2
    line = "----------"
    x1 = dic["empty_1"] + " | " + dic["empty_2"] + " | " + dic["empty_3"]
    x2 = dic["empty_4"] + " | " + dic["empty_5"] + " | " + dic["empty_6"]
    x3 = dic["empty_7"] + " | " + dic["empty_8"] + " | " + dic["empty_9"]
    playground = x1 + "\n" + line + "\n" + x2 + "\n" + line + "\n" + x3 + "\n"

    check = "123456789"
    count = 2
    player_1 = "X"
    player_2 = "O"
    current_player = ""
    flag = False

    print(playground)
    decision = str(input("Enter field-number: "))
    if count % 2 ==  0:
        current_player = player_1
    else:
        current_player = player_2

    field = "empty_" + decision

    if dic[field] in check:
        dic[field] = current_player
        print(dic["empty_2"]) # prints out "X"
        flag = True
    else:
        print("Can´t place there!")
        print()

    count += 1
    flag = False
    return dic
```

Comment: Of _course_ it prints out `2`; the immediately preceding statement forces it back to the condition where `2` is the value. Why do you expect anything else?

Comment: If it's somewhere else you expect an update to take place where it isn't reflected, can you [edit] the question to be more explicit about the distinction between desired and actual behavior?

Comment: (Similarly, a more minimal [mre] is always a good thing -- the less code you have that's unrelated to the actual problem, the more people can focus on the question itself).

Comment: `dic` probably should be a global variable that's initialized at the beginning of the game, rather than re-initializing it every time you call `user_input()`

Comment: Every time the `user_input` is called, `dic` is set to it's initial condition at the beginning of the function itself. The function does what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

For the ease of understanding let's do a review on your code

**Code review**

```
def user_input():

    # Just Define the `dic` at the beginning of the function
    dic = {
        "empty_1": "1",
        "empty_2": "2", # Here "empty_2" is "2", 
                        # Otherwise "2" is assigned into dic["empty_2"]
        "empty_3": "3",
        "empty_4": "4",
        "empty_5": "5",
        "empty_6": "6",
        "empty_7": "7",
        "empty_8": "8",
        "empty_9": "9",
    }
    print(dic["empty_2"]) # And here you are Just calling the value of
                          # dic["empty_2"] just right after assigning "2"
                          # as its value

    # So the result is "2"

    line = "----------"
```

**How to fix the mistake you have done?**

Right now the `dic` is a private variable inside the function. You have to define the `dic` outside of this function as a **global variable** and remove the `dic = {...` part from the function.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly sure what you intended to do with the dict but if it should track, which board location is occupied by which player you might want to restructure your dict like this:

```
board = { "1" : "empty","2" : "empty","3" : "empty",
       "4" : "empty","5" : "empty","6" : "empty",
       "7" : "empty","8" : "empty","9" : "empty"
}
```

And later in your code when the curent player "claims" a position you can just get the board position by doing:

```
board["1"] = "Player1"
```

After each pick you check if the target state (3 in a row or non empty) is reached.

About your problem i would say you might want to have a look at poping values if you truly want to get rid of key-value pairs because otherwise those keys stay in the dict until the reference to it is destructet (dic = None).

As stated i am not 100% sure what you tried to achieve with the dict.